# unable to query EntityFramework shared dbcontext reliably

Tags: entity-framework, objectcontext, dbcontext, objectdisposedexception, code-first

I'm trying to share a simple DbContext with 4 DbSets among multiple repositories, each of my repositories inherit from this base class

```
 public class CodeFirstRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private static MyContext _ctx = new MyContext();
        protected MyContext Context
        {
            get { return _ctx; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Question**: is this an appropriate way to share a connection between repositories?

I'm getting intermittent failures in my unit tests when accessing the various repositories.  An exception is thrown from the repository method GetEntityByName

```
public IOfferResult GetEntityByName(string name)
{
   return Context.Entities.Where(o => o.Name == name).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

> Test method
>   Tests.Service.TestDelete
>   threw exception:  System.ObjectDisposedException: The ObjectContext
>   instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations
>   that require a connection.

if the database already exists, the code executes as expected.  it also works when  i change the implementation of GetEntityByName(string name) to the following non-performant code

```
public IOfferResult GetEntityByName(string name)
{
   foreach (OfferResult offer in Context.Offers)
   {
       if (offerName.ToLower() == offer.Name.ToLower())
       {
           return offer;
       }
   }
}
```

**Question**: what is going on here?

bear in mind that if the database exists when i run the tests i don't get the error at all.

tia,
jt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is arising because you are treating the `DbContext` like a singleton by declaring it as a `static` field, but then you are treating it like it like a transient instance by disposing it as soon as *any* instance of `CodeFirstRepository` gets disposed. For example:

```
using (var r = new PersonRepository())
{
   // do something
} // When you hit the end of this block, your static DbContext is disposed.
using (var r = new IOfferRepository())
{
    r.GetEntityByName("test"); // this will fail because the context is still disposed.
}
```

You should **not** share contexts this way. If you really want all of your repositories to use a single instance of the `DbContext`, remove the call to `Context.Dispose()`. This would fix the problem you're getting right now, but it will likely introduce other problems in the future.

But I would strongly caution against using a single `DbContext` in a scenario where multiple threads could be trying to access it simultaneously. According to the `DbContext` [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

You'd be better off just removing the `static` keyword from your field.

Comment: would injecting the context class into the repositories using UnityContainer and the transient lifecycle be a better alternative?  also can you tell me why it's considered poor form?

Comment: @Jason: I fleshed out my answer a little. The most important thing is to not have the field be static. Beyond that, I would say dependency injection is preferable to instantiating it directly. You can use a transient lifecycle and continue disposing it with your repository. That would probably be simplest. There are other strategies (per-request if it's a web app, e.g.) that could work, but unless you can guarantee you won't try accessing the context from multiple threads at once, the transient lifecycle is the safest.